# Unexpected text 'example_filename.jpg" />' on product page. Only one product has this problem

Tags: magento2

On out page one product has a strange problem. Above the gallery there is an unexpected string with the name of the jpg that is shown in the gallery as main picture.

Compared to the other products, I can't find what's wrong with this one.

[image]

https://staging.relax-pillow.de/kirschkernkissen-direkt-befullt-waschbar.html

What can I do to find out what's wrong. Do any of you have a tip how to find out why this string is there?

---

I add my small python script, that finds such broken products. Just in case someone else has the same problem and wants to check his site for these problematic products:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sitemap_url = ".../sitemap.xml"

# Fetch the sitemap.xml file
response = requests.get(sitemap_url)
response.raise_for_status()

# Parse the sitemap.xml file
sitemap_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "xml")
urls = [loc.string for loc in sitemap_soup.find_all("loc")]
print(f"Found {len(urls)} urls")

# Found errors go in here
urls_with_visible_image_names = []


def check_for_condition(url):
    print(f"Processing {url}")
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    if ".jpg" in soup.get_text():
        urls_with_visible_image_names.append(url)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
    for url in urls:
        # No need to check images,... that are also in Magentos sitemap
        if not url.endswith(".html"):
            continue
        executor.submit(check_for_condition, url)

# Print URLs where the specified string is present and data-active-tab > 0
if len(urls_with_visible_image_names) > 0:
    print("URLs with image names visible:")
    for url in urls_with_visible_image_names:
        print(url)
else:
    print("No problems detected")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there may be some incorrect or a mismatched code in the product description or template file for this specific product or this page.

You can try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check the product description in the backend to see if there are any HTML tags or code that may be causing the issue.
2. Check the template file for this product in your theme to see if there are any unexpected strings or code. The template file for the product page is usually located in app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view.phtml.
3. Check if any customizations or extensions have been added specifically to this product or a Product Detail Page that may be causing the issue.
4. It is possible that this issue is caused by a caching problem. You can try clearing the cache to see if that resolves the issue.
5. If you are still unable to find the source of the issue, you can try temporarily disabling any third-party extensions one by one to see if the issue goes away.
6. Finally, you can try creating a duplicate of the product and see if the issue persists in the duplicate. If it does not, then you can delete the original product and use the duplicate instead.

Comment: Hi Charmi Patel, thank you for your answer! Very much appreciated!
It was not exactly one of you points, but they guided me in the right direction.

I try to explain the problem I found.

My sister uploads her images with names such as "170 x 36 cm Stillkissen als Babynest.jpg".

Magento seems to escape the name and replaces spaces with underscores etc... 
But something is still problematic somewhere. After uploading a manually renames picture the problem was still there (something seems to be also cached...)
After renameing the beginning of the name, the problem was gone.
1/2

Comment: So there seem to be more than 1 condition that causes the problem. I could not exactly pinpoint the exact problem, but it has to do with the naming of the uploaded images.

I told her now, that she should take care of the names beforehand and avoid underscores, umlauts (äöü),...

Thanks again Charmi Patel for the push in the right direction!!

2/2

Comment: I'm glad that my response was helpful in reaching you to the solution.
Yes, Magento does replace spaces with underscores in uploaded file names, but it seems that in your case, the file name contained characters that were causing issues, such as umlauts (äöü). It's a good idea to avoid using special characters in file names to prevent any potential issues like this.

Comment: Also, clearing the cache can often help in resolving unexpected issues like this one. So, in case you face similar issues in the future, make sure to clear the cache and check if the problem persists. Thank you for sharing the solution to the problem you faced. It can be helpful for others who might face a similar issue.